# Spring Boot fails to run schema.sql with dependency on spring-cloud-starter-config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

My spring boot 2.0 application recognizes and runs schema.sql to initialize my embedded h2 database. But when I add spring-cloud-starter-config dependency the application no longer runs the schema.sql. To illustrate, use [spring initializr](http://start.spring.io) to generate a Spring Boot 2 (v2.0.1) application with dependencies on:

- web
- rest repositories
- jpa
- h2
- config client

Add an entity:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Room {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

//...getters and setters

}
```

A Repository for the entity:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long> {

}
```

Main class is unchanged from what initializr generated:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Add schema.sql and data.sql file to the base folder under resources. These are used by Spring Boot to create and populate the underlying table for the entity:

schema.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE ROOM(
    ROOM_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
);
```

data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO ROOM (NAME) VALUES ('Piccadilly');
INSERT INTO ROOM (NAME) VALUES ('Cambridge');
INSERT INTO ROOM (NAME) VALUES ('Oxford');
INSERT INTO ROOM (NAME) VALUES ('Manchester');
```

Replace the empty application.properties with this application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
```

Now, run the application and go to http://localhost:8080/rooms. Application will fail with JdbcSQLException showing that the table does not exist:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ROOM" not found; SQL statement:
>   select room0_.room_id as room_id1_0_, room0_.name as name2_0_ from room room0_

Now go into pom.xml and comment out the reference to spring-cloud-starter-config dependency:

```
<!--
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
-->
```

Restart the application and everything now works! Open http://localhost:8080/rooms in your browser and you will find the expected JSON result (with the 4 rows) is returned. This tells me it was the spring-cloud-starter-config dependency that stopped Spring from executing the schema.sql and data.sql to initialize the database.

How can I get Spring Boot to execute the schema.sql and data.sql files when I use the Spring Cloud dependency?

Comment: can you post your main class?

Comment: Added the main class. It's unchanged from what initialzr generated.

Comment: I ran into this as well. See comment https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue but during tests execution with H2 database schema creation. I've just tried newer versions - `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.2.RELEASE` and `Finchley.RC2` for Spring Cloud and it works in my case.

Spent few minutes with your example - reproducible with Spring Boot 2.0.1 and Spring Cloud Finchley.RC1, but works fine with 2.0.2 and Finchley.RC2.
I didn't manage to find github issue, but looks like it was fixed.

Comment: The latest works for me too. Using `Finchley.RC2` AND `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.3.RELEASE`.